# Kubernetes job does not recognize environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I am using the following job template:

```
 apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: rotatedevcreds2
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rotatedevcreds2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: shell
        image: akanksha/dsserver:v7
      env:
      - name: DEMO
        value: "Hello from the environment"
      - name: personal_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: rotatecreds-env
            key: personal_aws_secret_access_key
      - name: personal_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: rotatecreds-env
            key: personal_aws_secret_access_key_id
      - name: personal_GIT_TOKEN
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: rotatecreds-env
            key: personal_git_token
        command:
         - "bin/bash"
         - "-c"
         - "whoami; pwd; /root/rotateCreds.sh"
      restartPolicy: Never
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

The shell script runs some ansible tasks which results in:

```
    TASK [Get the existing access keys for the functional backup ID] ***************
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "aws iam list-access-keys --user-name ''", "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

However if I spin a pod using the same iamge using the following

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: rotatedevcreds3
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: rotatedevcreds3
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: shell
        image: akanksha/dsserver:v7
        env:
        - name: DEMO
          value: "Hello from the environment"
        - name: personal_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rotatecreds-env
              key: personal_aws_secret_access_key
        - name: personal_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rotatecreds-env
              key: personal_aws_secret_access_key_id
        - name: personal_GIT_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rotatecreds-env
              key: personal_git_token
        command:
         - "bin/bash"
         - "-c"
         - "whoami; pwd; /root/rotateCreds.sh"
      restartPolicy: Never
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

This creates a POD and I am able to login to the pod and run `/root/rotateCreds.sh`

While running the job it seems it not able to recognose the aws cli. I tried debugging `whoami` and `pwd` which is equal to `root` and `/` respectively and that is fine. Any pointers what is missing? I am new to jobs.

For further debugging in the job template I added a sleep for `10000` seconds so that I can login to the container and see what's happening. I noticed after logging in I was able to  run the script manually too. `aws` command was recognised properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely your `PATH` is not set correctly, 
a quick fix is to define the absolute path of aws-cli like `/usr/local/bin/aws` in `/root/rotateCreds.sh` script

Comment: Indeed that was the issue. After giving absolute path things worked. Again after logging into the pod manually I could see the path. I am wondering why aws is not set in path when I run job! The image I am using already has the path set.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I added an export command to update the path and that fixed the issue. The issue was: I was using command resource so it was not in bash environment. So either we can use a shell resource with bash argument as described here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html
or export new PATH.